# ARCore calculate Pose based on latitude/longitude

Tags: android, arcore, android-augmented-reality

The global task sounds like: we have a **lat/long** and I wanna put an object, which will look on those coordinates. Exactly like **AR Navigation.**

Comment: any luck finding the solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution?